# Only return elements in array that are higher in index if duplicated

Tags: javascript

I can remove all duplicates from an array using this function:

```
function make_unique(array) {
    return array.reduce(function(p, c) {
        if (p.indexOf(c) < 0) p.push(c);
        return p;
    }, []);
};
```

But this gives me the lower indexed element of any 2 duplicates. I need a way to return the "higher" indexed duplicate of any elements that are duplicated in the array.

So in the following array:

```
array = ["bob", "chris", "susan", "steve", "melissa", "steve", "bob"]
```

it would give me elements 1 (chris), 2 (susan), 4 (melissa), 5 (steve), 6 (bob)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simpler "make unique" function using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var uniques = array.filter(function(v,idx) {
  return array.indexOf(v)===idx;
})
```

Need it filtered "from the tail"? use [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf):

```
var uniques = array.filter(function(v,idx) {
  return array.lastIndexOf(v)===idx;
});
```

But bear in mind that this doesn't make any sense: if you're removing duplicates, there *are no differences* between the earliest and latest instance, so their ordering should be completely irrelevant.

If the order does matter, then there's something you're not telling us that is important in disambiguating duplicates, and you should surface that in your code (or abandon the requirement of course)

Comment: You could avoid two reverse operations by using `lastIndexOf`.
`array.filter(function(v,idx) {return array.lastIndexOf(v)===idx;});`

Answer (score 0):

How about use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) I think you don't have to create util functions.

in underscore.js

```
var array = ["bob", "chris", "susan", "steve", "melissa", "steve", "bob"]
var result = _.uniq(array.reverse()).reverse();
```